# Assembly Code in a C Function

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, gdb

I'm trying to write a quadratic root function in assembly code in a .c file, and I've been having trouble getting the syntax in the AT&T format correctly. The errors I'm getting are: "in function quadratic root, undefined named operand EAX, undefined named operand 1, unknown register name ST1 in asm". Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// function for checking that assembly code is computing the correct result
double quadraticRootC(double a, double b, double c)
{
return (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
}

double quadraticRoot(double a, double b, double c)
{
// assembly code to calculate the quadratic root
    double root1;
asm( 
    //"quadraticRoot:                      "
             //"enter  0,0               "
             "fld    %[a]               \n" // a
             "fadd   %%ST               \n" // 2a
             "fld    %[a]               \n" // a, 2a
             "fld    %[c]               \n" // c,a,2a
             "fmulp  %%ST(1)            \n" // ac, 2a
             "fadd   %%ST               \n" // 2ac, 2a
             "fadd   %%ST               \n" // 4ac, 2a
             "fchs                      \n" // -4ac, 2a
             "fld                       \n" // b, -4ac, 2a
             "fld    %[b]               \n" // b, b, -4ac, 2a
             "fmulp  %%ST(1)            \n" // b*b, -4ac, 2a
             "faddp  %%ST(1)            \n" // b*b-4ac, 2a
             "ftst                      \n" // compare (b*b-4ac) with 0
             "fstsw  %%AX               \n" // store status word in AX
             "sahf                      \n"
             "jb     no_real_roots      \n"
             "fsqrt                     \n" // sqrt(b*b-4ac), 2a
             "fld    %[b]               \n" // b, sqrt(b*b-4ac), 2a
             "fchs                      \n" // -b, sqrt(b*b-4ac), 2a
             "fadd   %%ST(1)            \n" // -b+sqrt(b*b-4ac), sqrt(b*b-4ac), 2a
             "fdiv   %%ST(2)            \n" // -b+sqrt(b*b-4ac)/2a, sqrt(b*b-4ac), 2a
             "mov    %%EAX, %[root1]    \n"
             "fstp   %%qword, %[EAX]    \n" // store root1                    
             //"fchs                    \n" // -sqrt(b*b-4ac), 2a
             //"fld    $b               \n" // b, sqrt(b*b-4ac), 2a
             //"fsubp  %ST1             \n" // -b-sqrt(b*b-4ac), 2a
             //"fdivrp %ST1             \n" // -b-sqrt(b*b-4ac)/2a
             //"mov    %EAX, (root2)    \n"         
             //"fstp   %qword[EAX]      \n" // store root2
             "mov      %%EAX, %[1]      \n" // real roots exist
             "jmp      short done       \n"
   "no_real_roots:                    \n"
             "sub      %%EAX, %%EAX     \n" // EAX = 0 (no real roots)
             "done:                     \n"
             :"=m" (root1)
             :[a] "m" (a), [b] "m" (b), [c] "m" (c), [root1] "m" (root1)
             :"ST(1)"

   //return(root1);                 
   // done:
         //"leave\n"
         //"ret\n" 
);

return(root1);
}

// main
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
double  a, b, c;
double  root, rootC;

printf("*\n");  
if (argc != 4) {
    printf("need 3 arguments: a, b, c\n");
    return -1;
    }
a = atof(argv[1]);
b = atof(argv[2]);
c = atof(argv[3]);
root = quadraticRoot(a, b, c);
rootC = quadraticRootC(a, b, c);

printf("quadraticRoot(%.3f, %.3f, %.3f) = %.3f, %.3f\n", a, b, c, root, rootC);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The assembly code can be found starting on page 456 of "Assembly Language Programming in Linux". [See: http://www.slideshare.net/guestacf37f1/guide-to-assembly-language-programming-in-linux ]

The problem is that this code is not suitable for "cut & paste" into the gcc 'inline assembly' function 'asm()'.

For an example of gcc inline assembly, see the example on page 458 in the function "array_fsum()".  Specifically, notice how parameters are passed to the inline assembly code:

```
double array_fsum(double *value, int size)
   {
   double sum;

   asm("          fldz;                     "
       "add_loop: jecxz   done;             "
       "          decl    %%ecx;            "
       "          fadd1   (%%ebx, %%ecx,8); "
       "          jmp     add_loop;         "
       "done:                               "
        :"=t"*(sum)            /* output */
        :"b"(value), "c"(size) /* inputs */
        :"cc");

   return(sum);
   }
```

There is no need for "%define a qword[EBP+8]\n" 'enter','leave', etc., for gcc inline assembly.  Input, output and clobbered registers are associated in the last three lines.

Hence, the code indicated in the question is intended to be assembled to an object file by an assembler.

Comment: I changed some of the syntax, and it is almost able to compile except the 2 errors "undefined named operand eax", and "undefined named operand 1", anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: @bluelegend8000, it is difficult to speculate on the cause without seeing the context.  Perhaps it would be best if you posted your current code in a new question?

Comment: I posted the entire .c file in the question and edited it, it's basically the instructions from page 458 in the book you posted, but I'm trying to translate the code from Intel to AT&T format. I think the problem is in the clobbers/inputs/outputs, but I'm not sure.